# change a copy of a sound file name before email it

Tags: objective-c

I am sending a sound file to email , but i want to change its name just for the email.

lets say i take some `sound.caf` , in my folder , i want to leave its name just like that ,but to take a copy of it ,change its name, and then send it.

i will show how i send email, and i need the simplest way to change the file name without affecting the original :

```
//send email log-------------------------
NSLog(@"mail");
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"your email"];
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

NSString *sound=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%d.caf",[memoryInstnace getSoundToEdit]];  //here, i need to change the name of the copy .

NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *dataPath = [[paths2 objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:sound];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"caf" fileName:sound];//

NSString *emailBody = @"my sound  ";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[picker setSubject:@"  new message "];

//display the view
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:picker.view];
//[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the file name you like here:

```
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"caf" fileName:myFileName];
```

and it will be received as `myFileName` instead of `sound`. Indeed, you are just attaching some data to your email message; this is unrelated to where the data came from (it could be a file, the network, etc); when attaching, you specify the name under which the data will be recognized as an attachment on the receiving end.